# Regexp: Limiting where and how often certain chars are allowed

Tags: java, regex

I have some form numbers I need to validate.  I've tried multiple attempts but am not getting it right yet.  While much is allowed in a form number there are some limits I need to impose:

All of these rules should be enforced:

- A-Z  allowed but not required (see bullet 4)
- 0-9  allowed but not required (see bullet 4)
- period (decimal point) and dash, if present, only allowed once per form number  . -
- Minimum length is one character and it cannot be a space, dash or period
- multiple spaces are allowed but two spaces may not be next to each other; also no leading or trailing spaces are allowed

This is what I had before but not all the above rules were enforced.

```
[A-Z0-9]([A-Za-z0-9 -.])*[A-Z0-9]
```

So these would be examples of valid form numbers under the new requirements:

```
123 
123 456 
A1 IL 23 MN 
CL-100 2.0
```

These would be examples of invalid form numbers under the new requirements:

```
123   456
25! 25
25-IL 30-1
aa bb CC
```

Comment: What language are you using the regex from?

Comment: xanotos: It is going to be used in a Java web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
^([A-Z0-9]|(?! )(?!.* $)(?!.*  )(?!.*-.*-)(?!.*\..*\.)(?![.-]$)[A-Z0-9 .-]+)$
```

There are two parts. The first one `[A-Z0-9]` checks for a single character. If it isn't a single character then there are some exclusion rules `(?! )(?!.* $)(?!.*  )(?!.*-.*-)(?!.*\..*\.)(?![.-]$)` (in order): no beginning with space, no ending with space, no consecutive double spaces, no two `-`, no two `.`, no single character `.` or `-` followed by end-of-string. Then there is the "base" pattern (one or more of) `[A-Z0-9 .-]+`

Note that you'll have to escape the `\` with another `\`, so `\\`.

Comment: xanatos:  Thanks, that appears to get many of them but it still allows a single period or dash to be the form name.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be all in one regex for some reason? You could go through and match for `\s\s`, and make sure that returns false. then you can go through each character and make sure that not more than 1 of them is a `.` and not more than one of them is a `-`. You can also check for no leading or trailing spaces, or you can be kind to your users and simply trim the input. You can then make sure that you have at least one character, and if the length is exactly one character, it is not a dash or a period.

Finally, since all of your other conditions are now satisfied, you can match the string against `[A-Z0-9 -.]*` and you will have your answer.

Based on your unsuccessful regex, I suspect you have a lot more conditions you actually want met, but hopefully this was enough help to allow you to figure out how to meet them on your own.

Comment: Alexander Corwin: I can certainly do the trim, but the rest needs to be one regexp if possible.  The system accepts one regexp to be used for validation. johkar